# Hive LIKE [0-9]

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to write a HIVE case statement in which if a field contains either the number 8/9 as the first character and any number between 0-9 in the second character and any letter between A-E in the final field that it would strip it from the string.

The code that I have that works (for the most part) is:

```
Case When Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '9_A' or 
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '9_B' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '9_C' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '9_D' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '9_E' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '8_A' or 
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '8_B' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '8_C' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '8_D' or
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '8_E' or
    Then
        Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3)
    Else
        Null
    end as DRVD,
```

What I would like (at doesn't seem to work) is

```
Case When Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) like '[8-9][0-9][A-E]'
       Then
          Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3)
       Else
          Null
       end as DRVD,
```

The input values can look like:

```
01512723290C
0151272329-C
ABC01199862590A
ABCD2642454890A
```

What I'm looking for the output to be is:

```
01512723290C      - 90C
0151272329-C      - Null
ABC01199862590A   - 90A
ABCD2642454890A   - 90A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a regular expression.  Based on your *code*:

```
(Case When Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) rlike '^[8-9][0-9][A-E]$'
      Then Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3)
 end) as DRVD,
```

I don't find that your code matches the description.

Regular expression matching in Hive uses `rlike` or `regexp` (see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)).

Comment: I ended up using the following:

 Case When Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3) rlike '[8-9][0-9][A-E]'
  Then
   Substr(Upper(Trim(MBRCHR)),-3)
  Else
   Null
  end as DRVD,

This worked perfecty